# Remove files from a bare Git Repository Globally

Tags: git

I would like to remove a couple big files someone pushed into our git repository, so everybody else may pull from the repo without downloading them.

I already tried ignoring those files, and also removing/commiting/pushing them from the host that pushed them with no luck.

I have access to the server and the bare repo

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**git filter-branch** is your answer here.

From the bare repository, you have several choices.

1) You want to remove a file or files, from every commit.

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter \
               'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch junk/bigfile' -- --all
```

or

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter \
               'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r junk/' -- --all
```

2) You want to find a file, regardless of its path, and remove all history of its existence..

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter \
      'mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE /tmp/index;
       GIT_INDEX_FILE=/tmp/index git ls-files -s|
       grep -v FILENAME|git update-index --index-info' -- --all
```

3) You want to find a specific committed file, and remove only that file.  For example if you commit a large binary, and later replace the file with a smaller file, you need to find the blob containing the original large file, and erase it.

```
$ git ls-tree -r <commit> | grep SOMEFILE
100644 blob 4cbedad5b4ab88f700bf27ae5a32bdb3627fa632    SOMEFILE
$ git filter-branch --index-filter \
      'mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE /tmp/index;
       GIT_INDEX_FILE=/tmp/index git ls-files -s|
       grep -v 4cbedad5b4ab88f700bf27ae5a32bdb3627fa632|
       git update-index --index-info'  -- --all
```

Each time you do this, the current set of "refs" or branch heads is backed up into the refs/original directory.  You can always copy these back to refs/heads to restore your repository.

If the file(s) you are removing result in an empty commit, add the '--prune-empty' option to the git-filter-branch command line.  This will allow git to completely discard the commit.

As long as refs/original contains the original heads, git will never prune the excised files or blobs.

Once you are completely happy with the results, the repository itself can be shrunk

```
$ rm -rf refs/original
$ git fsck
$ git prune
$ git gc
$ git repack -a
```

And you are done.

> **WARNING**:  git-filter-branch will REWRITE EVERY COMMIT.  Make sure
>   there are no uncommitted/unpushed working changed.  Everyone must be
>   committed and pushed before doing this.

Once complete, each person should do the following
    $ git fetch --all
    $ git reset --hard @{upstream}

Comment: Be aware that the filter-branch step may take hours on a large repository with a long history.

Comment: 1) was a life saver for a file that BFG would not remove because it was "dirty" i.e., it was referenced in a branch

Answer (score 2):

You have to *rewrite* the history using `git filter-branch` or similar techniques. See this example to remove the file `Rakefile` [in the github help](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data):

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' \
  --prune-empty -- --all
```

You should be aware that everyone that already cloned your repository needs to hard reset their branches to the one on the remote or they'll reintroduce the files.

Comment: "--tag-name-filter cat" is redundant.  Don't add tag-name-filter unless you plan on changing the tag names.

Comment: @Dave I copied it straight from the github help page. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the files you want to remove were commited on their own, you can use the rebase command to simply eliminate the commit.

1) checkout a working copy

```
$ git clone -s bare_repo.git
$ cd bare_repo
```

2) use git-log to find the commit

```
$ git log
384b1a3306c1247559563f855e2adf5ced80678b good commit
8abb0e7cf306ceb209cb5c4aa3b422b9460fdb64 bad commit
```

3) Use git rebase to rewrite the history, leaving out that commit

```
$ git rebase -i 8abb0e7cf306ceb209cb5c4aa3b422b9460fdb64^   <--- note the ^**
```

4) The bad commit should be the top line.  Delete the line, save and exit.
5) git-log should show your history with the bad commit gone.
5) push the changes back.  Use the -f flag to force the updates

```
$ git push -f origin master
```

6) You can now delete the working tree

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) which is much, much faster than git-filter-branch.  However, it will not remove files that are referenced in a branch. Consult [Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22649532/2009203) to remove those.